# Displaying Map Openstreetmap on Android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

Please can someone help me! I can't display my map and I don't have idea anymore about the problem. When I try to run it, I receive an error message: unfortunetly Other has stopped.

I saw in other forum that I can load support-v7-appcompt but it doesn't work for me!
Please help me because I must continue this project.

Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foramtion.other"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.formation.other.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/Theme.AppCompat" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.foramtion.other;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapActivity;
import org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MapView mapView = new MapView(this);
        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMapFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/OsMap.map");
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/test.txt");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        setContentView(mapView);
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<!--     <TextView -->
<!--         android:layout_width="wrap_content" -->
<!--         android:layout_height="wrap_content" -->
<!--         android:text="@string/hello_world" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Map doesnot work on emmulator use genymotion

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have try LinearLayout instead of RelatvieLayout but it doesn't work, and like I never call the activity_main.xml in my MainActivity, I think it's not necessary!

Comment: And about the genymotion, I will see how to use it! thanks! I will come back to give the result!